# Overloading global operator new (non-POD)

Tags: c++, overloading, new-operator

**Consider the following example:**

```
void * operator new(size_t size)
{
    void * p = malloc(size);
    //Error handling supressed...
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void * p)
{
    free(p);
}

class foo
{
public:
    foo() { baz = 4234; }
    int baz;
};

class bar
{
public:
    bar() { np = new foo(); }
    ~bar() { delete np; }
    foo* np = nullptr;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bar * a = new bar();
    printf("%d\n", (*a).np->baz);
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why does this work. How can the constructor be called under these circumstances? Neither class id POD (Plain old data), they have a constructor and destructor! `static_assert` grants me `foo` or `bar` are not POD, so...

Why does the `printf` output the value `4234` on the console? What is happening? Shouldn't this give me something unexpected? I'm using visual studio 15 compiler.

Comment: Why do you think your constructors wouldn't get called?

Comment: Why should this do something unexpected? You seem to think something is really wrong here, but I'm not seeing what you think is broken. `operator new` gets memory, that's it; it's not responsible for object construction. When you *use* the `new` keyword, it combines a call to `operator new` followed by constructing into the memory returned from `operator new`. Replacing `operator new` doesn't block that second step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [[class.ctor]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#8), default constructors are called to create class objects of dynamic storage duration created by a new-expression in which the new-initializer is omitted (does not matter if it is the default `operator new` or user-defined `operator new`).

If you do not provide any constructors for a class the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member. 
And if the implicitly-declared default constructor is not defined as deleted, i**t is defined**.

So the default constructors are called for `foo` and `bar` in this case.

Comment: It seems I totally misunderstood the meaning of the operator new. So this means the problem would be something like allocating the memory for a class pointer **directly** with `malloc`. As @ShadowRanger also said in the comment above `operator new` does not perform the same as `new`?

Comment: @Primemaster: Yes, `operator new` functions like `malloc`. The `new` **expression** first calls `operator new` followed by the call to the constructor.